# Porting X11 app to Win Api - Enter/Leave Notify events

Tags: winapi, x11

In my X11 app I handle `EnterNotify` and `LeaveNotify` messages. What is the closest equivalent to those events in Win Api ? Should I use `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` to implement Enter and Leave Notify logic or there is other way ?

Comment: `WM_MOUSELEAVE`/`WM_MOUSEMOVE` are the messages to use for this. See [Why is there no WM_MOUSEENTER message?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031013-00/?p=42193) for an example.